# Formatting large author list and affiliations with IOP template

Tags: formatting, templates, author, journal-publishing

I'm writing a publication using the [IOP journal template](https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/questions/latex-template/) but have been struggling to format the list of authors, which contains over 100 entries, each with their own sets of affiliations. The intended outcome is to have the authors' names side by side, with footnotes pointing to a list of affiliations at the end of the list, such that any common affiliations or cases with multiple addresses can be handled. This should look something like:[image: The intended outcome]

but as it stands, I am getting something like this instead:[image: The present state]

I'm trying to format it by inputting the list of authors as

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}
\newcommand{\gguide}{{\it Preparing graphics for IOP Publishing journals}}
%Uncomment next line if AMS fonts required
%\usepackage{iopams}  
\begin{document}

\title[Author guidelines for IOP Publishing journals in  \LaTeXe]{How to prepare and submit an article for 
publication in an IOP Publishing journal using \LaTeXe}

\input{authorlist.tex}

\vspace{10pt}
\begin{indented}
\item[]August 2017
\end{indented}
```

where `authorlist.tex` contains:

```
\author{John Doe} \address{address 1}
\author{Ann Chovey} \address{address 2}
\author{Hazel Nutt} \address{address 2}
\author{Marsha Mellow} \address{address 3}
\author{Barb Akew} \address{address 3, address 4}
```

I've tried to follow solutions that use `authblk`, but this seems to conflict with the `iopart` class as the list of authors and affiliations disappears altogether when compiling.